# what is the maximum number of fields(columns) supported in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I tried to create the hive table having >1000 fields( columns) using complex data structure.But I ended up with the below error.

> Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Add request failed : INSERT INTO "COLUMNS_V2" ("CD_ID","COMMENT","COLUMN_NAME","TYPE_NAME","INTEGER_IDX") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) 
>   NestedThrowables:
>   java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "COLUMNS_V2" ("

But it is successful when I reduce the field count to 500.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the value of maximum number of characters allowed. That can be done by changing the value for table "SERDEPROPERTIES" and column "PARAM_VALUE".

The table is present in MySQL, which serves as a metastore.

Increase the value for the column type and the issue would be resolved. You could increase it to something varchar(15000) or whichever value seems better to you.

Answer (score 0):

A hack that worked for avro based tables is to create table with reduced schema (small number of columns). Once table is created replace reduced schema file with complete schema.

Comment: Although this may answer the question it qualifies more as a comment than an answer.